read() appends extra 'FF' at the end
I am trying to build a redis clone. I've set up simple TCP server that listens for client's request, and processes them.
//snippet begin
        if (server_fd == -1) {
                printf("Socket creation failed: %s...\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        int reuse = 1;
        if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
                printf("SO_REUSEADDR failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = { .sin_family = AF_INET ,
                .sin_port = htons(6379),
                .sin_addr = { htonl(INADDR_ANY) },
        };

        if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0) {
                printf("Bind failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        int connection_backlog = 5;
        if (listen(server_fd, connection_backlog) != 0) {
                printf("Listen failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Waiting for a client to connect...\n");
        client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
   
        while (1) {
                client_fd =  accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_len);

                if (client_fd == -1) {
                        printf("Accept failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                        return 1;
                }

                child_pid = fork();

                switch (child_pid) {
                        case -1:
                                printf("Fork failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                                return 1;
                        case 0:
                                // child process
                                close(server_fd);
                                handle_client(client_fd);
//snippet end

//snippet begins
        ssize_t bytes_read;
        char client_request[1024];
        char *command;

        bytes_read = read(client_fd, client_request, sizeof(client_request));
        if (bytes_read == -1) {
                printf("Read failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
                return;
        }
        if (bytes_read < 2) {
                handle_send_usage(client_fd);
                return;
        }
        extract_command(client_request, command);

I was having issue with extracting the command. When I examine the exact bytes of client_request on the line containing extract_command, I see extra FFs being appended to the original request.
gef➤  x/gx client_request
0xffffffffee98: 0x0000ffff474e4950

Please clarify if this is a usual behavior, or I am missing something?
I'm using
echo -n "PING" | nc localhost 6379

to send the request

TCP data is just a byte stream so there's no guarantee that a write of N bytes at one side will result in a single read of N bytes at the other side.  You also haven't shown the implementation of extract_command -- is it treating client_request as a null terminated char array... or something else?  Please provide a [mcve] if possible.

I don't see how extract_command() can do its job correctly without being told how many bytes were actually read.

What is the value of bytes_read? Only those bytes in client_request are meaningful.

And note well that there are no requirements on the bytes of client_request that are neither initialized in the declaration nor later assigned values.  They could have any value, on any read, including 0xff.

Since you're only sending 4 bytes with echo -n "PING", only 474e4950 are part of the valid data. ff is just what happened to be in the buffer.

if you look at client_request before and after read() you'll see the same 0000ffff in that part. Nothing was added, it was just left unchanged.

If I do echo -n  "PING" | nc localhost 6379 and observe from gdb just before it executes the extract_command, I see the following
gef➤  print bytes_read
$9 = 0x4
gef➤  x/gx client_request
0xffffffffee98: 0x0000ffff474e4950
gef➤


@Barmar so the only way for me to extract command will be to take the help of bytes_read variable?

Yes. You also need to define your application protocol so you can tell where the end of messages is. Some protocols use newline as a delimiter, some send fixed-size binary data, some send the length as a prefix.

HTTP is a mixture. The HTTP header is newline-delimited, the Content-Length: header tells how many bytes are in the body.

My mistake was assuming that client_request would be a null terminated string. I'm new to systems programming
Thank you everyone! I've found the answer!

@Barmar unless the body is chunked or self-delimiting (ie, MIME), in which case then Content-Length doesn't apply.

@RemyLebeau I know that, it was just a simple example. And that's just more mixing (each chunk has a length prefix). There's also the "Connection: close" mode.

Suggestion: do memset(client_request, 0, sizeof(client_request)); before read(). Also, you may try setting flags (4th argument of read) to MSG_WAITALL, to wait block until full request is satisfied.
